# Binary function of type and wrapped type

Tags: haskell, types, wrapper, typeclass

I have a binary function that can work on a type `a` and a wrapped version of the same `W a`, through a class (in fact it's `Num`) . I want to check that it works the same way on both and try to write the following test:

```
prop_binary :: (a -> a -> a) -> W a -> W a -> Bool
prop_binary op wrappedm@(W m) wrappedn@(W n) =
  m `op` n == result
  where (W result) = wrappedm `op` wrappedn
```

But this doesn't compile. I've tried a few different things, including adding a `Num` constraint, but I can't get it going.

EDIT: I came up with the following not very nice solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, FlexibleContexts, Rank2Types - #}
prop_binary :: (Eq b, Num b, Num (W b)) => (forall a. (Num a) => a -> a -> a) -> W b -> W b -> Bool
(...)
```

But maybe there's something better?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: It was something along the lines of "expexted type a, got type W a"

Comment: Your type signature is binding a to the unwrapped W, and then you're trying to call the same function on a W. Perhaps you could pass op to prop_binary twice, and use one for the wrapped type, and one for the unwrapped type? With a type signature of `Eq b => (a -> a -> b) -> (W a -> W a -> W b) -> W a -> W a -> Bool`

Comment: Yes that's an option, thanks! I wonder if there's another one too (apart from that in the EDIT of the OP)

Comment: What is wrong with the implementation you've written? How would you like to see it improved? That is, how would you like to use your function that the current implementation doesn't permit?

Comment: Hm I guess my objection is mostly esthetic at this point (three language extensions, `Num` constraint in three places). Also I know that the type is either `a` or `W a` but the function is too general; `a` or `W b`. EDIT: oops, there's a typo on the last bit, I'll edit

Comment: Since the operation is binary, could you make it a `Semigroup` or `Monoid`? If so, you might need to pass the operation as an argument at all. Instead, you could simply write a property that the wrapped type produces the same result as the unwrapped monoid or semigroup.